# What is this type of chart called? And how to I make one?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

This chart permits the user to calculate one unknown as a function of two known values.

[image: Climb/Descent Gradient Graph]

What is this type of chart called? How do I calculate the three lines? (I suspect I can fix the two lines on the outside so it's just a matter of calculating the third line in the middle).

In my particular case I want to do this for the Kinetic Energy formula (KE = 1/2 * Mass * Velocity ^ 2).

Any code that implements this would be great. Ideally in R, but I'm easy!

Comment: In `python` I would use [`secondary_yaxis`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.secondary_yaxis.html).

Comment: This is a nomogramm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomogram
there is this on Github: https://github.com/achekroud/nomogrammer